# Declare Firebase Notification TTL on python PyFCM

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

This code is working as expected, but all the notifications sent are set default expiry time (28 days).

```
from pyfcm import FCMNotification
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>")
data_message = {"foo":"bar"}
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, data_message=data_message)
```

How can I set the expire time to **less than default** so very old notifications dont make their way to the users devices?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the [PyFCM documentation](https://github.com/olucurious/pyfcm) on GitHub I could find the solution:

> time_to_live (int, optional): How long (in seconds) the message
> should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The
> maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks. Defaults to `None`
> which uses the FCM default of 4 weeks.

Example implementation to set notification to expire after 1 hour if not delivered:

```
push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, data_message=data_message, time_to_live=3600)
```